# reg query inside unknown keystring

Tags: windows, networking, windows-registry, interface

Is there a way to reg query into an unknown keystring?  What I mean by this is if I do

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\
```

the entries will differ on every single server.  However, in our environment, the information inside 1 of these entries will always be static.  Is there a way to search inside all of these entries?  Something I can use inside reg query (or any other command for that matter) that would allow a search inside unknown subkeys?  This obviously doesnt work, but to give an idea:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\*
```

or

`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{~}`

Anything that will continue the search pattern inside whatever keys the original `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\`  passes?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can be done with a /s at the end of the query

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\ /v "search string" /s
```